# Getting difference of value between two adjacent records in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

(Editing my post with data and expected result as per replies.)

I have a table which looks as follows. I would like to compute the difference in `Score` between two adjacent records.

```
ID          TimeStamp               Score
1002010     9/26/2015 11:24:08 PM   32
1002010     9/28/2015 10:12:57 PM   38
```

This is what I have tried.

```
SELECT
   [current].ID,
   [current].Score,
   ISNULL(convert(int,[next].Score), 0) - convert(int,[current].Score)
FROM
   RiskPredLog AS [current]
LEFT JOIN
   RiskPredLog AS [next] ON [next].ID = (SELECT MIN(ID) 
                                         FROM TableName 
                                         WHERE ID > [current].ID)
WHERE
   [current].ID = '1002010'
```

But I always get the difference to be -1.

Expected result

```
 ID         TimeStamp               Score
 -----------------------------------------------
 1002010    9/26/2015 11:24:08 PM   NULL
 1002010    9/28/2015 10:12:57 PM   6
```

Comment: please post the expected result as well

Comment: Does adjacent mean consecutive? and what is the sort order for your top 3 rows (they look to have the exact same ID & TimeStamp)>

Comment: @vkp  have edited my post above. please check

Comment: @Amit, have made an edit above.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using? (It will make a big difference for this kind of problem.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `lead` to get the value from the next row and use it for subtraction. Note that this function is available in sql server 2012 and later versions.

If you need `null` to be the result when there is no leading row, remove the `isnull` condition.

```
SELECT
ID,
Score,
ISNULL(convert(int, lead(Score) over(partition by id order by timestamp)), 0) 
- convert(int, Score)
FROM RiskPredLog 
-- where ID = '1002010'
```

Comment: this works. thank you.
How can I find the difference in TimeStamp between the two adjacent rows as well.

Comment: @vkp, got it thank you. I used
datediff(hour,ISNULL(convert(datetime, lag(TimeStamp) over(partition by PatientID order by Timestamp)), 0),TimeStamp) as Aging,

Answer (score 0):

You can implement `ROW_NUMBER()` in place of `lead/lag` if you are using pre-2012 SQL Server:

```
SELECT
   [current].ID,
   [current].Score,
   ISNULL(convert(int,[next].Score), 0) - convert(int,[current].Score)
FROM
   (Select *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID,TimeStamp) as rn from RiskPredLog) AS [current]
LEFT JOIN
   (Select *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID,TimeStamp) as rn from RiskPredLog) AS [next]
      ON [next].rn = [current].rn + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```sql
SELECT  r.ID,
        r.Score,
        r.Score - ISNULL(LEAD(r.Score) OVER (ORDER BY r.TimeStamp DESC),0) AS ComputedScore
FROM    RiskPredLog r
```